# Parsing or Splitting pysnmp output to update into database

Tags: python, split, pysnmp

I am trying to store the generated PYSNMP data into mysql database.

The data generated is a tuple or a list—I am not sure.

The output that I get is 9016, but when I wish to save it to the database it is something like `(OID(1.3.6.1.1.18443.1.1.), Integer(9016)`. I got to know about this after I go a print value about it.

I tried with `output = re.split(r'', val)`. Here `val` has the above mentioned string/tuple.

Need help in getting just the integer data.

Comment: You are getting `(OID(1.3.6.1.1.18443.1.1.), Integer(9016)` and you only want `9016`?

Comment: @SameerKatti: please clarify your question—it is hard to understand what you're asking exactly and what is the data you are working with.

Comment: Can you show some of the previous code? I'd like to see how your using the pysnmp library

Comment: @thefoutheye: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Erik: the data i get through Pysnmp using a particular OID.

Comment: Sorry for the indentation error. Less characters.

Comment: @SameerKatti: please don't paste such long snippets of code in comments.

Comment: @Erik: i am new to Stackoverflow and Python. Apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pysnmp returns a sequence of two-component tuples. These components are OID and value. That is called variable-binding in SNMP.

So what you see might be:

```
varBinds = [ (ObjectIdentifier('1.3.6.1.1.18443.1.1'), Integer(9016)) ]
```

which is a list of variable-bindings.

To save just the value part of the first variable binding in a sequence you could need to:

```
varBind = varBinds[0]
oid, value = varBind
str(value)
```

or

```
int(value)
```

depending on the database data type.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using a bit complex method to get `value.`